# Error 4: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFramework or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's definition does not match

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I keep getting the error "Error 4: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.25.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)" when trying to compile my csproj. Any help would be greatly appreciated

here is my ucsdb.edmx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
<!-- EF Runtime content -->
<edmx:Runtime>
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
  <Schema Namespace="ucsdbModel.Store" Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
ProviderManifestToken="5.6" Alias="Self"
          
xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityType Name="Clan">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ClanId" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ClanId" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="LastUpdateTime" Type="datetime" Precision="0" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Data" Type="text" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="Player">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="PlayerId" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="PlayerId" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Avatar" Type="text" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="GameObjects" Type="text" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="ucsdbModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="Clan" EntityType="Self.Clan" Schema="ucsdb" store:Type="Tables" />
      <EntitySet Name="Player" EntityType="Self.Player" Schema="ucsdb" store:Type="Tables" />
    </EntityContainer>
  </Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
<!-- CSDL content -->
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="ucsdbModel" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false"
          xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityType Name="Clan">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ClanId" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ClanId" Type="Int64" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="LastUpdateTime" Type="DateTime" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Data" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="65535" 
FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="Player">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="PlayerId" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="PlayerId" Type="Int64" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="Avatar" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="65535" 
FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
      <Property Name="GameObjects" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="65535" 
FixedLength="false"
                Unicode="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="ucsdbEntities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
      <EntitySet Name="Clan" EntityType="Self.Clan" />
      <EntitySet Name="Player" EntityType="Self.Player" />
    </EntityContainer>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" 




xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs 
">
    <EntityContainerMapping 
StorageEntityContainer="ucsdbModelStoreContainer" 
CdmEntityContainer="ucsdbEntities">
      <EntitySetMapping Name="Clan">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="ucsdbModel.Clan">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Clan">
            <ScalarProperty Name="ClanId" 
ColumnName="ClanId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="LastUpdateTime" 
ColumnName="LastUpdateTime" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Data" 
ColumnName="Data" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
      <EntitySetMapping Name="Player">
        <EntityTypeMapping 
TypeName="ucsdbModel.Player">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Player">
            <ScalarProperty Name="PlayerId" 
ColumnName="PlayerId" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="GameObjects" 
ColumnName="GameObjects" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Avatar" 
ColumnName="Avatar" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
      </EntitySetMapping>
    </EntityContainerMapping>
  </Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
</edmx:Runtime>
<!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW 
HERE) -->
<Designer 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
<Connection>
  <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    <DesignerProperty 
Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" 
Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
  </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
</Connection>
<Options>
  <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" 
Value="true" />
    <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" 
Value="false" />
    <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" 
Value="false" />
    <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" 
Value="false" />
    <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" 
Value="None" />
  </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
</Options>
<!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) - 
->
<Diagrams></Diagrams>
</Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: How did you add the reference? Did you install a NuGet package?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes I did and I tried various versions too.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use MySql.Data.EntityFramework.8.0.25, but the program does not have this dll file or use another version.

Click on the project's directory, right-click References and open Manage NuGet Packages.
[image]

Search for MySql.Data.EntityFramework to see Version. I hope I can help you.
[image]